# End of input at line 1 column 1 path $ within send a json array

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit2

i want to send a json array to server in diffrent versions of retrofit.but i just give this error:

End of input at line 1 column 1 path $

my java code is:

```
private void setOnClickSubmit() {
    btn_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            load_submit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btn_submit.setAlpha(0.5f);
            btn_submit.setText("");
            btn_submit.setEnabled(false);
            btn_exit.setAlpha(0.5f);
            btn_exit.setEnabled(false);
            ansInf = intent.getExtras().getParcelableArrayList("answers");
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
            JSONObject jsonObject =new JSONObject();
            try {
                jsonObject.put("user_id","17");
                jsonObject.put("mikhay", new SecurityCode().getSecCode());
                jsonObject.put("price", "200");
                jsonObject.put("cat_id", "20");
                jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
                for(int i = 0 ; i < ansInf.size() ; i++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject1 =new JSONObject();
                    jsonObject1.put("question",ansInf.get(i).getQuestion());
                    jsonObject1.put("type", ansInf.get(i).getType());
                    jsonObject1.put("field", ansInf.get(i).getAnswer());
                    jsonArray.put(jsonObject1);
                }
                Log.i("test3", "setOnClickSubmit: " + jsonArray);

                ApiClient.getInstance().getApi().CatInf(jsonArray).enqueue(new Callback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<Status> call, Response<Status> response) {
                        Log.e("test3", "onResponse: "+response.body().getStatus() );
                        if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body().getStatus().equals("successfull")){
                            load_submit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            btn_submit.setAlpha(1f);
                            btn_submit.setText("ثبت نهایی");
                            btn_submit.setEnabled(true);
                            btn_exit.setAlpha(1f);
                            btn_exit.setEnabled(true);
                            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                                    .make(findViewById(android.R.id.content)
                                            ,"با موفقیت ثبت شد. به سفارشات مراجعه کنید.",
                                            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).
                                            setAction("سفارشات", new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(View view) {

                                                }
                                            });
                            snackbar.getView().setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(PriceActivity.this, R.color.blue8));
                            snackbar.setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                            snackbar.show();
                        }
                        else {
                            load_submit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            btn_submit.setAlpha(1f);
                            btn_submit.setText("ثبت نهایی");
                            btn_submit.setEnabled(true);
                            btn_exit.setAlpha(1f);
                            btn_exit.setEnabled(true);
                            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                                    .make(findViewById(android.R.id.content)
                                            ,"مشکلی پیش آمد",
                                            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).
                                            setAction("باشه!", new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(View view) {

                                                }
                                            });
                            snackbar.getView().setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(PriceActivity.this, R.color.blue8));
                            snackbar.setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                            snackbar.show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<Status> call, Throwable t) {
                        load_submit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        btn_submit.setAlpha(1f);
                        btn_submit.setText("ثبت نهایی");
                        btn_submit.setEnabled(true);
                        btn_exit.setAlpha(1f);
                        btn_exit.setEnabled(true);
                        Log.e("test3", "onFailure: "+t.getMessage());
                        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                                .make(findViewById(android.R.id.content)
                                        ,"خطا برقراری ارتباط با سرور",
                                        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).
                                        setAction("باشه!", new View.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(View view) {

                                            }
                                        });
                        snackbar.getView().setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(PriceActivity.this, R.color.blue8));
                        snackbar.setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                        snackbar.show();
                    }
                });


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

}
```

and my interface is:

```
@POST("add_service")
Call<Status> CatInf(@Body JSONArray jsonArray);
```

and my log is:

> [{"user_id":"17","mikhay":"hi","price":"200","cat_id":"20"},{"question":"نوع
> فضای مورد نظر خود را مشخص کنید:","type":"radio","field":"تجاری/
> اداری"},{"question":"آیا این مکان خالی از وسایل یا کلید نخورده
> است؟","type":"radio","field":"خیر"},{"question":"متراژ فضای مورد
> نظر","type":"radio","field":"50 الی 70 متر"},{"question":"برآوردتان از
> مدت زمان لازم برای انجام کار چند ساعت است؟","type":"radio","field":"5
> ساعت"},{"question":"به متتخصص آقا نیاز دارید یا
> خانم؟","type":"radio","field":"خانم"},{"question":"خدمات مورد نظر خود
> را مشخص کنید:","type":"checkbox","field":"مرتب کردن داخل کابینت و
> کمد"},{"question":"آیا از حیوانات خانگی نگهداری
> میکنید؟","type":"radio","field":"خیر"},{"question":"آیا در محل شما
> بیمار مبتلا به کرونا حضور
> دارد؟","type":"radio","field":"خیر"},{"question":"توضیحات
> تکمیلی:","type":"text","field":"لات"},{"question":"عکس از محل
> تمیزکاری","type":"pic","field":"http://kara-service.ir/pl_include/pic/user__1__photo__72.jpg"},{"question":"تعداد
> زن و مرد","type":"gender","field":"1-0"},{"question":"جه زمانی به این
> سرویس نیاز
> دارید؟","type":"date","field":"1399/9/26"},{"question":"محل انجام
> سفارش","type":"address","field":"اصفهان خیابان کاوه"},{"question":"محل
> انجام سفارش","type":"text","field":"ددک"}]
>
> 2020-12-16 10:08:25.845 30914-30914/com.example.zafarapp E/test3:
> onFailure: End of input at line 1 column 1 path $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are use JSONArray?
You can create a model class, and pass it directly to body, retrofit GsonConverterFactory automatically converted it to json then, send to server.

For your model class, you can add all of your fields as parameter, and fill just required fields (Retrofit does not send null fields.)

According to the above, your model class will look like this:

```
public class Data {
    @SerializedName("field")
    public String field=null;
    @SerializedName("type")
    public String type=null;
    @SerializedName("question")
    public String question=null;
    @SerializedName("cat_id")
    public String catId=null;
    @SerializedName("price")
    public String price=null;
    @SerializedName("mikhay")
    public String mikhay=null;
    @SerializedName("user_id")
    public String userId=null;
}
```